# Continuing string on the next line

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to declare an Array of Strings with the following code:

```
Dim flagNames() As String: flagNames = Split("Afghanistan,Albania,Algeria,Andorra,Angola,AntiguaandBarbuda,Argentina,Armenia,ASEAN,Australia,Austria,Azerbaijan,Bahamas,Bahrain,Bangladesh,Barbados,Belarus,Belgium,Belize,Benin,Bermuda,Bhutan,Bolivia,BosniaandHerzegovina,Botswana,Brazil,Brunei,Bulgaria,BurkinaFaso,Burundi,Cambodia,Cameroon,Canada,CapeVerde,CaymanIslands,CentralAfricanRepublic,Chad,Chile,China,Colombia,Comoros,Congo(DemocraticRepublic),Congo(Republic),CostaRica,Croatia,Cuba,Cyprus,CzechRepublic,Denmark,Djibouti,Dominica,DominicanRepublic,EastTimor,Ecuador,Egypt,England,EquatorialGuinea,Eritrea,Estonia,Ethiopia,EuropeanUnion,Fiji,Finland,France,Gabon,Gambia,Georgia,Germany,Ghana,Greece,Greenland,Grenada,Guatemala,GuineaBissau,Guinea,Guyana, _
Haiti,Hawaii,Honduras,HongKong,Hungary,Iceland,India,Indonesia,Iran,Iraq,Ireland,Israel,Italy,IvoryCoast,Jamaica,Japan,Jordan,Kazakhstan,Kenya,Kiribati,Kosovo,Kuwait,Kyrgyzstan,Laos,Latvia,Lebanon,Lesotho,Liberia,Libya,Liechtenstein,Lithuania,Luxembourg,Macedonia,Madagascar,Malawi,Malaysia,Maldives,Mali,Malta,Mauritania,Mauritius,Mexico,Micronesia,Moldova,Monaco",",")
```

It's too long to fit on a line, so I'm using the line continuation character `_` but it ain't working.

When the code fits on a line, it does work, so I know it's not an issue with the command itself, just the length.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
Dim flagNames() As String

flagNames = Split("Afghanistan,Albania,Algeria,Andorra,Angola,AntiguaandBarbuda," & _
          "Argentina,Armenia,ASEAN,Australia,Austria,Azerbaijan,Bahamas,Bahrain," & _
          "Bangladesh,Barbados,Belarus,Belgium,Belize,Benin,Bermuda,Bhutan",",")
```